# Can a moderator delete a question of mine?

Tags: support

I'd like to ask if a moderator could delete a recent question of mine that was not welcomed very well by the community. I've tried, but I'm unable to do so.

[Here it is.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/184015/83101)

It was deemed to be not good enough to stay open, but I see that it keeps being downvoted, and it is honestly quite annoying.

I would have deleted it myself, but like I said, I cannot.

Comment: in the future, bringing something to moderator attention will happen faster if you "flag" your question and pick "in need of moderator attention" :)

Comment: For the record, since the only answer on your question was your own, it would have been possible for you to delete it yourself by just deleting the answer first. The system won't stop you from self-deleting answers or unanswered questions.

Answer (score 7):

So you've posted a question you're not happy with and don't like that you're copping flak for it, and now wish for it to be removed. You have a few options here:

## 1. Leave it

It is not fair to simply remove content that you no longer like. The functional and spiritual nature of this site is that it's [community owned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18221/252593) (or more specifically 'StackOverflow owned'). As such, once you've put the content here, it no longer *belongs* to you, but to **us**; the community, as a whole. The only reason that your name is attached to content is for *attribution purposes* (rep is a side issue related to incetivising people to donate their content).

**Simply not liking something you've posted now is not reason enough to remove it.** As Animuson et al [have said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/252593):

> You should be willing to stand by all content you contribute to our network. If we notice a specific user continually requesting their name be removed from posts, that is a strong signal that you are not willing to contribute to this community in an effective and meaningful way and you may find yourself suspended from the site. We are not a platform for you to post or say whatever you want and then turn around to have your name removed from it.

So I suggest you suck it up and deal with it.

## 2. Disassociate the question from your account

You are in fact able to [disassociate posts from your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86618/252593). Simply:

- Click on '[Contact](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/contact)'

  - Found at the bottom of *every* page
- Describe your problem

  - Be sure to be specific; make sure you put a link to the actual post
  - Include a *good* reason why you should be disassociated from the content
- Send

Alternatively, you can raise a custom 'flag for moderator attention' on the post and request that a moderator perform the disassociation for you.

By the way, this simply removes the attribution that was applied to *you*, everything else remains in tact.

## 3. Ask a moderator to delete the content

This is highly discouraged, removing content on the sole basis of 'I don't like this; it's giving me downvotes' is not a fair use of this site. Even some 'bad content' is still good content to leave in place. Also, moderators shouldn't be spending time removing content that people no longer 'like'.

Having said that, you can apparently 'flag for moderator attention' and hope that they agree with you and can delete a post for you.

---

**Further reading:**

- [Why are some usernames on comments not a link to user profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290608/252593)
- [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA 3.0?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/252593)
- [No way to delete an answered question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86616/252593)
- [Who owns the content I post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18221/252593)

Comment: Strictly speaking, you do not need *any* reason for dissociating yourself from the content, "good" or otherwise.  The CC-BY-SA license includes an absolute right to such dissociation and says nothing about needing a reason for doing it.

Comment: @Kevin That's more of a StackExchange thing. The CMs and miss don't want to be constantly bothered by petty requests.

Comment: "The CMs" are Stack Exchange employees.  SE as a company has no legal right to ignore a valid request for dissociation.  So your suggestion that such a reason is required is very misleading.

Comment: @Kevin You're missing the point, it's not _my_ suggestion, it's the likes of Shog and co who suggest it.

Comment: In the link you provide to Shog's answer, he puts "include a good reason" under "delete the question," but not under "anonymize the question."  This is because a reason is not required for the latter.

Answer (score 4):

A moderator wasn't needed. It has received three delete votes from users (including myself) and has now been deleted.

[status-complete](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-complete)

Comment: I received a warning that could not be deleted because it already received answers. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Couldn't be deleted **by you**. Due to its downvotes, it can be deleted by the community